# Connecting to a remote database in D8

Tags: 8, database, configuration

I have the following params in **settings.php** to connect to an external database .

```
$databases['d8243']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'drupal8',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '123123',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '192.168.1.243',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

And am using the following code to access some data from the db .

```
\Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('d8243');
$query = "Select * from node__field_target_config_controller";
$result = db_query($query);
$obj = $result->fetchObject();
echo json_encode($obj);
exit;
```

My current server and the external db server are in a **`same network`** .

But am geting the following error :

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.245'      [error] (using password:
>   YES)' in
>   /var/www-drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php:149

Is there a different method to connect to remote db in D8 ? or how to do it ?

When i checked d6/d7 versions have an option to specify remote db like

**`$db_url = 'mysql://username:password@quranschools.org/databasename';`**

how to do this in D8 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like:

```
$other_database = array(
  'database' => 'drupal8',
  'username' => 'root', // assuming this is necessary
  'password' => '123123', // assuming this is necessary
  'host' => '192.168.1.243', // assumes localhost
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql', // replace with your database driver
);
// replace 'YourDatabaseKey' with something that's unique to your module
Database::addConnectionInfo('d8243', 'default', $other_database);
db_set_active('d8243');
// execute queries here
db_set_active()
```

You can access your other database like above. For reference check [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-connect-to-multiple-databases-within-drupal) link.

Comment: am not clear with the **YourDatabaseKey** , what should given in there ?

Comment: Edited answer. Please check

Comment: am getting the same error : exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.245'      [error]
(using password: YES)' in /var/www-drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/Connection.php:149
**Note that the access deny problem is for the server 245 which is my current server**

Comment: Check host as you said 'host' => '192.168.1.243' but in error, host is showing as 192.168.1.245

Comment: yea am connecting to the remote db (192.168.1.243) from my current server (192.168.1.245). host is given as **192.168.1.243** . And my code is in a custom module .

Comment: Can you try using "getConnection" instead of "addConnectionInfo".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67234/discussion-between-a-ajay-reddy-and-rubberduckisking).

Comment: sorry Thats giving me a result ,but the data is of my current server (192.168.1.245)

Answer (score 0):

Set up your main database and external database in your settings file:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'mysite_local',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => 'root',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);

$databases['migration_database']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'drupal8',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '123123',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '192.168.1.243',
  'port' => '3306',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

Then in your code that needs to access the other database, you can switch between databases, using:

```
db_set_active('migration_database');
```

and to switch back:

```
db_set_active('default');
```

Comment: am getting the same error : exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.1.245' [error] (using password: YES)' in /var/www-drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Driver/mysql/C‌​onnection.php:149 Note that the access deny problem is for the server **192.168.1.245** which is my current server

Comment: Yes .245 is your current IP, that’s what the error message says. you can read it as “someone from this ip tried to log in but they’re not allowed”. It doesn’t refer to the mysql server ip

Comment: @Clive so its a mysql permission issue for the **root@192.168.1.245** to the server **192.168.1.243** right , not the issue of host specified ? And how to resolve it ?

Comment: @Clive Yes , it was a **permission** issue for the 245 user to access 243 . If some one answer it properly , i  can accept it